# MapStruct generated class is empty in Java 21

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct, java-21

I want to use MapStruct in my project but the generated class is empty.
This is how I'm doing that :

Country.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@EqualsAndHashCode()
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name="country")
public class Country implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String frenchName;
    private String englishName;
    private String shortName;
    private String logo; // just store the logo name like France.jpeg. And we will put the folder path in application.properties
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "continent_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Continent continent;
    
}
```

CountryDto.java

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CountryDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String frenchName;
    private String englishName;
    private String shortName;
    private String logo;
}
```

CountryMapper.java

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

import com.simubasket.jeu.dto.CountryDto;
import com.simubasket.jeu.model.Country;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CountryMapper {
    CountryDto mapToCountryDto(Country country);
    Country mapToCountry(CountryDto countryDto);
}
```

And this is the CountryMapperImpl.java generated during the build.
I don't know why the two methods are empty ?
I probably miss something somewhere but I don't know what. I already used MapStruct in an other project in the same conditions but everything was ok.

Thank you in advance

CountryMapperImpl.java

```
import com.simubasket.jeu.dto.CountryDto;
import com.simubasket.jeu.model.Country;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2024-01-06T22:50:31+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 21.0.1 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class CountryMapperImpl implements CountryMapper {

    @Override
    public CountryDto mapToCountryDto(Country country) {
        if ( country == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CountryDto countryDto = new CountryDto();

        return countryDto;
    }

    @Override
    public Country mapToCountry(CountryDto countryDto) {
        if ( countryDto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Country country = new Country();

        return country;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check that lombok `annotationProcessor` stands before mapstruct `annotationProcessor`

Comment: Thank you, it works by adding this dependency into the pom.xml => lombok-mapstruct-binding

Answer (score 1):

Seems it's Lombok issue. first make sure annotations processors already enabled in your IDE and `lombok-mapstruct-binding` dependency already present in you project.

And if you are using Gradle, first make sure you have version 8.5 (currently latest supported) and try to add this annotation processor config to your build Gradle file.

with `Gradle - Groovy`:

```
configurations {
  compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
  }
}
```

with `Gradle - Kotlin`

```
configurations {
  compileOnly {
    extendsFrom(configurations.annotationProcessor.get())
  }
}
```

Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/FouomaOscar/spring-boot-mapstruct-lombok-integration-demo-with-gradle-kotlin/blob/main/build.gradle.kts) with that configuration with Gradle Kotlin using Java 21.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, I'm using Maven. I will search for the same thing with Maven

Comment: It works by adding this dependency => lombok-mapstruct-binding

Comment: Great ! It seems that, this dependency is essential for Mapstruct to work well with Lombok.